# Send keybinds to a non-active window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, simulate

So this has been bothering me for quite a while now.
I have a program for sending keys to a window (user may select processes from a [CComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx), etc.), and I'm now trying for quite a while to figure out how it would be possible to send key-binds to a window (background !).
I know about this [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and the [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. I use neither of them in my current code, as they require the window to be in the foreground.

[image: Sending keys]

Short said, my program can send keys and text to any *(valid)* window.

```
PostMessage(m_hwndEx, WM_CHAR, nKey, 0x00140001);
```

I have tried various solutions with [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but nothing seems to work.
Assume the program sends <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (as example). How would this be possible ? I would appreciate some pointer function(s) or even an external library if the 'basic' functions do not work for this matter.
*I do **not** want the window to be in the foreground.*

Comment: The program is probably checking to see if `Ctrl` and `Shift` are pressed down. You could fake those two with `SendInput`. Then send `F` key separately through `WM_CHAR` or `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Comment: agreed with @BarmakShemirani, you can send the WM_KEYDOWN and add the flags (CTRL, SHIFT, ALT etc...) that you need. (PS: post the solution when you get it)

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx) - [When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/13/10499047.aspx) - [Posted messages are processed ahead of input messages, even if they were posted later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/31/10422524.aspx)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I'm not using `SendInput` for the reason I stated clearly in the question above. I'm totally aware that this would work for a `foreground window` but not for a `background window`. Right now I am trying to figure out if / how it would be possible to send system-keys to a window in background.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, but is there possibly any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` determines if `Ctrl`, `Shift`, or `Alt` key is pressed or not. This can only be faked with `SendInput` or `keybd_event`. It doesn't matter which window has focus. The program is doing something like this in `OnKeyDown`: `if ( (key == 'F') && (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) ) {//Shift+F detected}` or maybe it's checking in `OnKeyUp` or `OnChar`, who knows... You should also check if the program support UI Automation then you could skip all this.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani `It doesn't matter which window has focus.` Basically that would mean I use `SendInput` while my program is in foreground and has focus, and expect the input to be handled in the other window ? Does not seem possible to me in any case, or did I miss something in your comment ?